# Kendo-Knockout: tooltip on kendodropdownlist

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am using kendo-knockoutjs library. I have a kendo dropdownlist. I am trying to implement a tooltip on it, so that when the mouse is over some element of the dropdown, a message with the `title` value to be shown:

html:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="kendoDropDownList: {data: myData, value: myValue}" />
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var myViewModel = function () {
    this.myData = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
    this.myValue = ko.observable();
    this.title = 'This is a comment for' + this.myValue();
}

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

I found something similar here:

http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/eLnqs/1/

but I am not sure how to implement it in my scenario. I don't think I want taking reference to the widget in my viewmodel. Also when I pass `databound` option in my bindings and trying to call a function the bindings are broken

```
data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: SubMenuTypesOptions, value: SubMenuType, enabled: isEditable, dataBound: testFunction }"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhanasekaran/QZWPR/2/) is how you might do it without taking reference in data bound but using template option

```
<div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="kendoDropDownList: {data: myData, value: myValue,template:'<span title=\'${data}\'>${data}</span>',dataBound:testFunction}" />
</div>
```

also dataBound works...

Comment: This looks nice, but is it possible to show the title value from my viewmodel as tooltip, not the current value ?

Comment: yes have a look at kendo template for more options of how to refer various properties.